# Fetching Error Code in mule

Tags: exception, mule, mule-studio

I want to create a custom exception message in case exception is thrown by my mule service. In order to do that, i want to separately capture mule generated ErrorCode. Is there any property using which i can get that value? I tried using #[org.mule.config.ExceptionHelper.getErrorCode(Exception.class)]" but this returned -1 as a value instead of the actual exception code.

What method can i use to fetch ErrorCode?

Answer (score 1):

You are supposed to pass the class of the current exception, ie:

```
#[org.mule.config.ExceptionHelper.getErrorCode(exception.class)]"
```

`exception` is the current exception while `Exception` is the `java.lang.Exception` class for which there is no error code associated.

Comment: Hello David,

Thanks for your reply. But getErrorCode(exception.class) returns -1 as well and not the actual Exception Code.

Comment: Maybe the exception that has been caught is not a `MuleException`? What is the type of this exception?